# A question about theming of Plank dock - How do I give margin to the bottom of the dock

Tags: linux, ubuntu, themes, gtk2

I have a question about Plank dock application.

As you know Plank supports theming via `dock.theme` and `hover.theme` files in `.local/share/plank/themes` folder. I am using all of its padding options like `TopPadding`, `BottomPadding` etc and they are working perfectly.

But how do I provide margin to Bottom? I don't want it to be stick to the Bottom and I want to move it to a little bit up so there will be space between bottom of the monitor and bottom of the Plank. Otherwise I can't provide full Round corners it looks just ugly.

Does anyone know how to move Plank on screen?

Comment: did you solved?

Comment: Nope. I've changed to GNOME form MATE and decided to go for FloatingDock.